# slickgrid editor could be dynamically changed in different rows?

Tags: slickgrid

There is a requirement that we need to change editor of a column in different rows. In a column, we could use a textbox editor in some rows, and dropdownlist editor in other rows. In the slickgrid samples, the editor can be defined in the column options before inilization of slickgrid, but could it be redefined and changed after the data had been loaded? If the event would be fired in rowschanged event, and the function can embed a new editor in the current selected cell. This will be cool. Could someone make any sugguestions? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the slickgrid official website, a nice guy makes some suggestion for this questions.

https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/issues/581#issuecomment-16374880

Comment: It seemed that I have to change another way to finish my request.